# Reading id and value for a Node in NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, xml, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an XML node  like this:

`<State id="1"> AA </State>`

How can I read the value 'AA' ? I'm able to read the `id` value "1" using:

```
(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict { <br>

        //Extract the attribute here.
        aState.stateId = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Reading id value :%i", aState.stateId);
    }
    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}
```

But not able to read the value

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember, to do this you should implement this method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

Entire code will look like this:

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    foundState = [elementName isEqualToString:@"State"];

    }
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
      if (foundState) {
        [stringBuffer appendString:string];
      }
   }
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 

namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if (foundState) {
      NSLog(@"AA = %@", stringBuffer);
      foundState = NO;
    }
}
```